# Cannot find module 'it' when testing with mocha/chai

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I have a simple test

```
import {topNavigationLinks} from './navigation-links.js';
import {assert,should,expect=} from 'chai';
import {mocha} from 'mocha';


describe('Navigation Links', () => {
    it('should have the right value', function () {
      expect(topNavigationLinks(123).to.equal([]));
    });
});
```

but I keep getting this error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'it'
```

any clues?

Comment: [documentation says you need to put an it statement inside the describe](http://mochajs.org/)

Comment: editted the question, still same error

Comment: How do you run the tests? Are you using a module builder?

Comment: npm script "test-client": "mocha ./**/*.test.{jsx,js} --compilers js:babel-core/register --require setup.js",

Comment: Anything (else) in the console? Maybe a file failed to load?

Comment: Figured it out basically my package.json was going over all .js files as well including node_modules which did not contain obviously any it statements, therefore it failed. By excluding node_modules from the mocha runs everything passes now.

Answer (score 1):

You're not requiring `mocha` in your file you're testing with.

`import * as mocha from 'mocha';`

#### EDIT

You also shouldn't use [arrow functions](https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions) in mocha

Comment: took the arrow functions out and using now just function, same error

Comment: I'm assuming you installed this with NPM, have you tried rerunning `npm install`? Also what if you use `const mocha = require('mocha');` instead of using `import`?

Comment: Yup I have all this installed with NPM and I've tried mocha as a const and require

Comment: When running the tests you're executing them using `mocha` such as `mocha path/to/test.js`?

Comment: yes @peteb I have an npm script as follows "test-client": "mocha ./**/*.test.{jsx,js} --compilers js:babel-core/register --require setup.js",

Answer (score 1):

Error was in having node_modules as part of my mocha script. So it was going over all of the node_modules and obviously not finding an it statement. Removing that took care of it